# Return modal element, open it if necessary

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm refactoring my [PageObject](http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects) for my tests. Currently I'm checking the labels present in 2 different buttons in a modal.

```
/* home-spec.js */
it('Some test', function(){
        expect(homePage.getButton1Label()).toEqual(expectations.btn1);
        expect(homePage.getButton2Label(true)).toEqual(expectations.btn2);
});
```

Although this currently works I need to pass a variable indicating if the modal is open or not. That's the bit I'm trying to fix.

```
/* home-page.js */  
var HomePage = function () {

function getModalContent(modalName, isModalOpen){
    /* isModalOpen =  element(by.css('.modal-content')).isPresent(); */
    if(!isModalOpen){
        var manageProductsView = getUiView('SOME_VIEW');
        var btn = getButton(manageProductsView);
        btn.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
    }
    return element(by.css('.modal-content'));
}

function getButtonLabel(buttonBinding, isModalOpen){
    /* isModalOpen =  element(by.css('.modal-content')).isPresent(); */
    var modalcontent = getModalContent('MODAL_NAME', isModalOpen);
    var modalFooter = modalcontent.element(by.css('.modal-footer'));
    var btn = modalFooter.element(by.binding(buttonBinding));
    return btn.getText(); 
} 


    return {
        getButton1Label: function(isModalOpen){
            return getButtonLabel('btn1', isModalOpen);
        },
        getButton2Label: function(isModalOpen){
            return getButtonLabel('btn2', isModalOpen);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is remove that `isModalOpen` dependency but I don't seem to find the correct way to do it. The comments indicate what I've tried and seemed to be the way to go. Also tried to wrap it in the `then` block.

**EDIT**
Based on [Vlad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39529814/6822037) I edited my `getButtonLabel` function so it checks if the modal is open

```
function getButtonLabel(buttonBinding){
  return element(by.css('.modal-content')).isPresent().then(function(isModalOpen){
      var modalcontent = getModalContent('MODAL_NAME', isModalOpen);
      var modalFooter = modalcontent.element(by.css('.modal-footer'));
      var btn = modalFooter.element(by.binding(buttonBinding));
      return btn.getText(); 
  });
}
```

Was trying to avoid handling promises manually but I guess in some cases it's unavoidable

Comment: remove isModalOpen and instead of this check if the modal is visible in the if condition, use if(element(by.css('.modal-content')).isDisplayed())

Answer (score 2):

Your commented part is the way to go:

```
function getModalContent(modalName){
    var modalContent =  element(by.css('.modal-content'));
    var isModalOpen = modalContent.isPresent();
    return isModalOpen.then(function(open) {
        if(!open){
        var manageProductsView = getUiView('SOME_VIEW');
        var btn = getButton(manageProductsView);
        return btn.click()
            .then(function(){
                return modalContent;
            });
        }
        return modalContent;
    });
}

function getButtonLabel(buttonBinding){
    var modalcontent = getModalContent('MODAL_NAME');
    var btnText = modalcontent
        .then(function(content) {
             return content
                 .element(by.css('.modal-footer'))
                 .element(by.binding(buttonBinding))
                 .getText();
        });
    return btnText; 
}
```

Beware that the modal remains open after the test, you might want to add something to close it if it's open to maintain consistent state throughout tests.

It's much better to know for sure if it's open before doing operations on it, so that you can open it yourself if it isn't and you need it to be, instead of doing conditionals like these - they are expensive because of promise chaining.

My general feeling is that the logic looks a bit too complicated, you might want to refactor some of the stuff in the future :p

Comment: It helped. Based on your input I've updated my `getButtonLabel` function. Give it a look on the edit